# How to make sure generated random boundingboxes within another boundingbox are not overlapping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, polygon, shapely

I have a boundingbox

```
a = [233.9259,  16.3902, 356.8651, 426.9131]

import shapely.geometry
bbox = (233.9259,  16.3902, 356.8651, 426.9131)
polygon = shapely.geometry.box(*bbox, ccw=True)
polygon.bounds  # (233.9259, 16.3902, 356.8651, 426.913
```

and I randomly generated 10 random boundingboxes with the size `8x8`

```
import random
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = polygon.bounds
width = 8# to be defined
height = 8# to be defined
num_polygons = 10# to be defined
random_poly = []

while len(random_poly) < num_polygons:
  rand_x = random.uniform(min_x, max_x)
  rand_y = random.uniform(min_y, max_y)

  left = Point([rand_x, rand_y])
  bottom = Point([rand_x, rand_y - height])
  right = Point([rand_x + width, rand_y - height])
  top = Point([rand_x + width, rand_y])

  new_poly = Polygon([left, bottom, right, top])

  if polygon.contains(new_poly):
    random_poly.append(new_poly)
```

[image]

How to make sure these generated bounding boxes are non-overlapping?

Comment: Are you asking how to tell if 2 polygons overlap?  Are you asking how to tell if a polygon overlaps any of a list of polygons?

Comment: If you have only 10 boxes - you can simply compare each against the others in a trivial (quadratic complexity) way. It means around 50 comparisons and should be efficient enough in many applications.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks. Yes that is what I am looking for?

Comment: context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77496370/extracting-non-overlapping-square-regions-inside-a-bounding-box and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77492874/how-to-extract-non-overlapping-random-bounding-boxes-within-a-bounding-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending the code provided with one additional conditional will do the trick.

This may not be most performant way to do it, but seeing the example code that doesn't seem to be the objective.

```
import random

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import shapely

bbox = (233.9259, 16.3902, 356.8651, 426.9131)
bounding_box = shapely.geometry.box(*bbox)

min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = bounding_box.bounds
width = 8  # to be defined
height = 8  # to be defined
num_polygons = 10  # to be defined
random_polygons = []

while len(random_polygons) < num_polygons:
    rand_x = random.uniform(min_x, max_x)
    rand_y = random.uniform(min_y, max_y)

    left = Point([rand_x, rand_y])
    bottom = Point([rand_x, rand_y - height])
    right = Point([rand_x + width, rand_y - height])
    top = Point([rand_x + width, rand_y])

    new_poly = Polygon([left, bottom, right, top])

    if bounding_box.contains(new_poly) and not shapely.MultiPolygon(random_polygons).touches(new_poly):
        random_polygons.append(new_poly)
```

Comment: It raises an error `GEOSException: TopologyException: side location conflict at 297.67328165016056 354.16435925070033. This can occur if the input geometry is invalid.`